# Настройка прав доступа SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, есть таблица с данными:
[image: Table]

Есть пользователь "User14".
**Вопрос:** Можно ли настроить права так, чтобы выполняя обычный `SELECT`, пользователь получал информацию о конкретной организации? Чтобы в будущем каждый пользователь видел только доступную ему информацию **в общей таблице**.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)
Nov  1 2020 00:48:37
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )
 (Hypervisor)

Comment: Row-level security доступен начиная с SQL Server 2016 (13.x). Так что ограничить можно только на уровне программной логики на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Существует довольно часто используемая практика выдачи результатов не напрямую из таблиц, а с помощью процедур/функций (в зависимости от СУБД). Т.е. изначально делать выборку (SELECT) не из таблицы, а из функции, в которую, как вариант, можно передать параметр USER_ID, и в зависимости от преданного значения можно выдавать не только надлежащие строки, но и поля/столбцы.

К примеру, есть поле, содержимое которого доступно только пользователю А. При выборке из функции пользователем А в этом поле будут значения. Пользователю Б содержимое этого поля недоступно, соответственно, содержимое этого поля будет NULL.

- В SQL SERVER это решается через функции, возвращающие табличные значения (ITVF).
- В ORACLE DATABASE, как вариант, можно использовать конвейерные (PIPELINE) функции.

В обоих случаях пользователям не нужны права на SELECT из этой таблицы. Нужны только права на EXECUTE этой функции.

Таким образом, решается не только Ваша задача, но и закрывается возможная дырка в безопасности при получении сведений из таблицы напрямую - обычным SELECT'ом, прав на который ни у одного пользователя не будет.

Comment: в SQL Server есть решение через Row Level Security: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: RLS, к сожалению, не доступен на указанной в вопросе версии  SQL Server.